# Shutting down computer when no one is on servers

Tags: bash, minecraft, shutdown

I run multiple minecraft servers on my tower and am trying to figure out a script to run in the background that will check if no one has been on any of the servers for the past 30 minutes and then shut down the servers and computer. Then I will use my raspberry pi for wake on lan when someone wants to join.

I figured out how to shut down the servers using rcon and the wake on lan stuff. The main problem I have is figuring out the shutdown. The only thing I've been able to find is how to check if someone is on that specific IP using

```
lsof -iTCP:25565 -sTCP:ESTABLISHED
```

But I don't know where to go from there. I am using a Linux machine and most of my experience with bash files comes from setting up the servers and that's about it. Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: No way with a shell script. That check is only a momentarily status and you cannot be sure  that way if there hasn't been somebody on one of that servers for a short glimpse between your probes.

Comment: Yes, but my understanding was that I could probably do a loop that probes every minute or so and checks if someone is on any of them and then continues if no one is and once it reaches 30 minutes or so would be able to shut down. If someone was wanting to play I doubt I would miss them 30 times in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this then:

```
#!/bin/bash

PORTLIST="25565 25566 25567"
TIMEOUT=3600

let T=0
declare -i START
declare -i NOW
START=$(date +%s)

while [ $T -lt $TIMEOUT ] ; do
   sleep 30
   for PORT in $PORTLIST ; do
      if lsof -iTCP:$PORT -sTCP:ESTABLISHED >/dev/null ; then
         T=0
         START=$(date +%s)
         # starting over
         continue 2
         fi
      done
   NOW=$(date +%s)
   let T=NOW-START
   done
echo timeout
```

PORTLIST and TIMEOUT being the only variables to change

Comment: That seems to work perfectly so far! Thanks so much! I'm going to keep messing with it and testing it in different circumstances but for now, this works great!

Comment: If you like it, you may mark my answer as useful.